# Efficiently read CSV file into array of doubles in C

Tags: arrays, double

Looking for a more efficient method of reading a CSV file into a 2D array of doubles. My current code works okay but takes 2 minutes to read into the array.

The CSV file being read is as follows. The entire file contains 28,325,381 lines and is 1.8GB.

```
CoordinateX,CoordinateY,CoordinateZ,Pressure,Temperature,VelocityX,VelocityY,VelocityZ,
0,0,0.0904,33.5797,300,-0.00146382,0.000389435,-0.00147085,
0,0.0003,0.0904,33.5795,300,0.126682,-0.000382509,0.00330599,
0,0.0006,0.0904,33.5793,300,0.250278,-0.00151828,0.0100881,
0,0.0009,0.0904,33.5788,300,0.365407,-0.00287706,0.0184123,
...
```

The original code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    /* Declare file and character pointers */
    FILE *pFile_r = NULL;
    FILE *pFile_w = NULL;
    char *pCell;
    int n = 0, p = 0, number_properties = 8;

    /* Open CSV file */
    char buffer[128];
    pFile_r = fopen("G:\\csv\\coarse (19000 - 39000)\\39500.csv","r");

    /* Declare array */
    int array_total_nodes = 28325340; //number of nodes in array
    double **properties_array;
    properties_array = malloc(array_total_nodes * sizeof(double*));
    for (n=0; n<array_total_nodes; n++) {
        properties_array[n] = malloc(number_properties * sizeof(double));
    }

    /* Fill array */
    rewind(pFile_r);
    fgets(buffer, 128, pFile_r);
    while (!feof(pFile_r)) {
        pCell = strtok(buffer, ",");
        for (p=0; p<number_properties; p++) {
            properties_array[n][p] = strtod(pCell, &pCell);
            pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        fgets(buffer, 128, pFile_r);
        n++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This method is something simple I came up with. I'm hoping there is a more clever way that's faster. Your help is appreciated.

### Update

I have switched for fgets to fscanf as such...

```
while (!feof(pFile_r)) {
        fscanf(pFile_r, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,", &properties_array[n][0], &properties_array[n][1], &properties_array[n][2], &properties_array[n][3], 
                                   &properties_array[n][4], &properties_array[n][5], &properties_array[n][6], &properties_array[n][7]);
            n++;
        }
```

Reading in now takes 70 seconds as opposed to 120 (a 40% decrease). I would like to improve upon this further if possible.

Comment: Have you experimented with changing the buffer size? Why 128?

Comment: Yes, good point. I could shorten the buffer size to about 80 but I'm looking for a larger improvement than that alone. Thank you :)

Comment: I was thinking the opposite direction. 128 is surprisingly small. You obviously have a reasonable amount of memory to deal with the number of doubles you are reading. Have you tried increasing the buffer size?

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try filling the buffer with multiple lines before tokenizing and converting to double.

Comment: Also, are there a lot of repeated strings in the input file? It may be faster to do a map lookup than strtod.